# Docker API NodeJS

Tags: node.js, docker, request, unix-socket

I'm using the nodeJS `request` library to call a unix domain socket, specifically the Docker API. This works fine and returns a list of containers.

```
curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/v1.24/containers/json
```

However, this returns a `400400 Bad Request` and I'm not sure why

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://unix:/var/run/docker.sock:http:/v1.24/containers/json', headers="Content-Type': 'application/json" , function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)
    } else {
        console.log("Response: " + response.statusCode + body)
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you mount the docker socket when you run the container i.e

> ```
> docker run --name containera \
>   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
>   yourimage
> ```

Give this a shot to list your containers:

```
        let options = {
          socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock',
          path: `/v1.26/containers/json`,
          method: 'GET'
        };
        let clientRequest = http.request(options, (res) => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            let rawData = '';
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                rawData += chunk; 
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
                console.log(parsedData);

            });
        });
        clientRequest.on('error', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });
        clientRequest.end();
```

Answer (score 1):

While this can be done with request I would consider using Dockerode the Node SDK for Docker API as it handles the headers correctly and avoids issues like 400 Bad Request. Here is the NPM Link [Dockerode NPMJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode)