# Nodejs - using docker rest api's calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, rest, dockerfile

Is there any way in nodejs/js to call the Docker api that simulate the following:

`docker login -u username -p password registry`
I've the **username password** and the **registry**

I mean run a rest call that provide the registry username and password and get ok or error, this is to verify user successful login.

I found this reference but not sure if I can use a rest call to verify that user was connected succesfully

https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

for example, I see in the docks something like

`GET /v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>`

but didnt find something with user and password

Also found this

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/

I've also find this post which use some docker api but not exact what I need...
[Docker API NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114992/docker-api-nodejs)

But not sure how to send the username, password, registry.